# Stale Google Nearby notifications

Tags: android-notifications, google-nearby

I had a Beacon registered to Google Nearby and then created a new notification. I got these notifications just fine. Later, I deleted the old notification and created a newer notification for the same beacon. However, I still keep getting the same old notification (that doesn't exist anymore for the beacon) in addition to the new notification. I verified this again and again on the Google Beacon Dashboard that the old notification does not exist for the beacon. Where is this stale data coming from even though I see no evidence of the old notification's existence in the Beacon dashboard? Is this a known bug in Google Nearby Notifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bug for on device caching that previously saw the attachment from that beacon.  Other devices nearby that haven't seen the old attachments will not see them.

The bug is already fixed in our dev environment and will roll out in a later release.

Comment: That's great to know Tony. I look forward to seeing the fix soon.

Comment: can you also view http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38884247/nearby-notifications-when-beacon-is-inactive and let me know what you think. Thank you.

Comment: That other question is the same bug.

Comment: One more for you @Tony Tran....thank you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39049874/android-ble-scan-interval-for-nearby-notifications