# Nearby notifications when Beacon is Inactive

Tags: google-nearby

I continue to see notification's from a Google Nearby registered Beacon even when the Beacon is set to be INACTIVE in the Dashboard. Is this expected? I was hoping to not see the Nearby notifications any longer but I still see them constantly irrespective of the Beacon's state. Is this a known bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a caching issue on the local device only.  Once the message for that beacon is found and cached it stays on that device and associated with that beacon id.  Another device will not see that message.

That said, issue was found and already fixed and roll out in a later release.

Comment: Thanks much Tony. Do you have an idea on when these fixes will be coming out? A couple of weeks, months?

Comment: Tentatively, it's gonna be 2-3 months.  We don't know precisely until we get closer to that time frame.

Comment: Tony, will the new Nougat release have all these fixes for Nearby or will I just have to wait for a Google Play Services update?

Comment: Thank you. Hoping to see the Google Play Services update soon 'cause the caching issue is leading to a terrible user experience.