# Android BLE scan interval for Nearby Notifications?

Tags: android-notifications, google-nearby

What is the scan interval that is currently being used by Android for the Nearby Notifications feature (app-less)?

On a parallel note, does the stability value for the beacon have anything to do with this interval? How/If is the Nearby Notification affected when the stability value is changed between stable, portable, mobile & roving?

Answer (score 0):

Nearby Notifications scanning is also the same as Nearby Messages background scanning.  It does so at every screen on.

The stability of the beacon does not affect Nearby Notification.

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, a user will not get a notification unless the user is in the vicinity of the beacon AND turns on the screen? If the user does not turn on the screen and goes out of the range of the beacon, he'll never see the notification?

Comment: If my assumption of how this works is correct, this will never ever work for applications that would like to actively engage a user with nearby notification. It's fine even if the user sees the notification much later but he/she should see the notification eventually even if the user is out of the range of the beacon then. This sounds sooo broken to me Tony Tran. :(

Comment: Your understanding is correct.  User must be in the vicinity of the beacons and turn on their screens.  This is because the notification needs to be relevant to the user at the location and time.  If users is out of range of the beacon, it's no longer relevant and is stale.

Comment: Thank you Tony. I don't totally agree that the notification is stale. Let's say this was a retail offer valid for days that the user notices on the phone later at home. Even if the user is not in the vicinity, he may decide to go back to the retail location to take up on that offer. I can think of many such use cases. But I also understand that you have to balance spam vs. pertinent notifications so I understand your approach. But I'm not sold that proximity experiences needs to be only relevantwhen a user is in the range of the beacons. Appreciate your response though (very much)!

Answer (score 0):

According to this Google I/O talk : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Acdu2ZdBaZE&list=PLOU2XLYxmsILe6_eGvDN3GyiodoV3qNSC&index=28

If Location History is enabled on the device, BLE scan will also be done in the background. Although I cannot find the exact interval in the documentation.